# Вывести число просмотров за сегодня?

Tags: mysql

Подскажите как вывести число просмотров объявления за сегодня ?

У меня сейчас выводится общее число просмотров переменной вот этой строкой

```
введите сюда кодecho '<img class="glaz" src="/icon/glaz.png"width="16" height="13" title="Количество просмотров">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$row_Recordset1['counter'];
```

нужно к ней добавить число просмотров за сегодня что бы вышло так (просмотров 80 сегодня 5) и что бы все это обновлялось в 00.00 часов как это реализовать .

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Мало данных для осмысленного ответа. См. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Если просмотры - просто int поле, то просто еще 1 поле добавить на подобии views_today. Плюс сохранять дату последнего обновления. День прошел - при обновлении обнуляешь

Comment: @exvayn *Если просмотры - просто int поле* - то первый вопрос "Где?". Почти наверняка - в БД. А если так - то кому нужны переопределённые данные, элементарно получаемые запросом?

Comment: @Akina и как вы запросом получите из количества просмотров в виде одного числа количество просмотров за день?

Comment: @exvayn А какие сложности? ``SELECT COUNT(`open_datetime`) AS `total`, SUM(DATE(`open_datetime`) = @date) AS `daily` ``... только не *из количества*, а одновременно с общим количеством.

Comment: @Akina я имел ввиду просто 1 число в 1 поле (views_count) для каждого поста, которое увеличивается с каждым входом на страницу. А вы имеете ввиду отдельную запись для каждого входа. Не думаю что для автора вопроса было бы проблемой посчитать количество просмотров за сутки (и не только) имея записи отдельных просмотров.

Comment: @exvayn Не знаю, проблема это для автора или нет - вполне может быть, что и проблема. К тому же почти наверняка, реализовав просмотры "за сегодня", автор захочет (или автору захотят - руководство, оно такое...) "за вчера", "за последнюю неделю" и т.п. - нормальную статистику, одним словом. А потом и аналитику - просмотры утром-днём-ночью, в праздники, в выходные, летом и т.п... уж лучше сразу сделать нормально и фиксировать просмотры, а не из количество. Ну чтобы два раза не переделывать...

Answer (score 1):

Для начала надо определить понятие "сегодня" - с учетом временных зон это понятие явно не определено.

Варианта 2:

1. Без привязки к временным зонам просто считаем, что `сегодня := время с полуночи текущей даты до текущего времени в зоне Z`, где Z можно принять зону сайта, например Z := UTC+3
2. В более сложном варианте считаем, что зона определяется для каждого посетителя локально, кто-то зашел из UTC+3, кто-то из UTC+4, а где-то из UTC+2. У всех понятие "сегодня" будет разное

В случае сложного варианта 2 нужно будет помнить каждый просмотр, или чуток схалявить - помнить число просмотров за последние 24 часа. Там все решение упрется в аккуратный SQL и работу с временными зонами

Я рассмотрю простой вариант, первый.

Понадобиться 2 счетчика. Просмотров всего (total) и просмотров сегодня (today). Пока идет текущая дата, мы просто прибавляем каждый просмотр объявления в счетчик `today`, и всегда прибавляем `total`. А в момент перещелкивания даты мы обнулим `today`.

Событие сброса можно организовать как минимум двумя способами:

1. [Через date в записи] Запоминать в объявлении дату `сегодня`, и если при +1 просмотре объявления дата не равна сохраненной, делать сброс и сдвигать дату
2. [Через cron] Делать каждый день эту операцию по cron на сервере

Более простой для кода и переносимости вариант первый.

```
/* Функция вызывается каждый раз, когда мы добавляем просмотр объявления 
Необходимые поля в $record:
total - INT - счетчик просмотров за все время
today - INT - счетчик просмотров сегодня
date - DATE - дата последнего просмотра, то есть сегодня
*/
function AddView($record)
{
    if (date('Y-m-d') != $record['date']) {
        $record['today'] = 0;
    }
    $record['total'] += 1;
    $record['today'] += 1;
    // Каким-то образом записываем обновленную запись в базу
    // Можете заменить на прямой SQL или как у вас принято писать в базу
    return UpdateRecord($record);
}

/* Функция возвращает просмотры */
function GetView($record)
{
    return 'Просмотры: всего '.$record['total'].' / сегодня '.$record['today'];
}
```

Ну и добавить просмотры лучше до того, как отображать их количество

Comment: у меня на сайте есть подобная функция но она считает обявления а не просмотры echo '<div class="well-box-fon">На сайте <b>'.$u.'</b> объявлений - За сегодня <b>'.$count_seg.'</b> объявлений</div>';

Comment: Это хорошо, я рад за вас ) Значит осталось немного, просто сделать

Answer (score 1):

Если предположить, что:

1. Количество просмотров хранится в базе данных с разбивкой по объявлениям (например, как поле в таблице объявлений)
2. Статистика отдельных просмотров не хранится
3. Не заморачиваемся на зоны времени, работая по зоне и времени сервера

то:

1. Добавляем в таблицу (объявлений) поле просмотров за сегодня

   ```
   ALTER TABLE adverts ADD COLUMN daily_views INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;
   ```
2. Добавляем в код скрипта инкремент этого поля при очередном просмотре (так же, как инкрементируется поле общего количества просмотров `counter`)
3. Создаём в планировщике сервера задание, которое обнуляет поле суточных просмотров в 0:00 ежесуточно

   ```
   CREATE EVENT 
       ON SHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY 
       STARTS CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 DAY
       DO 
       UPDATE adverts SET daily_views = DEFAULT;
   ```
4. Запускаем планировщик

   ```
   SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
   ```

Альтернативный вариант - добавить поле просмотров за предыдущие дни `ALTER TABLE adverts ADD COLUMN prev_views INT UNSIGNED;`, и по эвенту копировать в него текущее состояние счётчика `UPDATE adverts SET prev_views = counter;`, тогда сегодняшние просмотры находим вульгарным вычитанием...

Comment: вот что нашла в базе   `counter` int(11) DEFAULT '0',  вроде это и есть просмотры

Comment: Ну я его назвал total_views - какая собсно разница как названо?