# Планировщик изменения записи в БД Php Symfony2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony2

Всем привет!
Интересует такой вопрос:
Как на Php (на проекте используется Symfony 2) реализовать изменение записей в БД по определенному времени.

Процесс таков:
Пользователь регистрируется на сайте. Потом для получения дополнительных привилегий, покупает пакет услуг (например "Премиум"). 
Этот пакет дается на 10 дней.
То есть, через 10 дней, в таблице юзера должно обновиться поле Package (к примеру) и установить значение поля "Standart".
Посоветуйте, как лучше поступить.

Заранее благодарен!

Comment: Создаёте задание в планировщике MySQL (CREATE EVENT), которое 1 раз, скажем, в час обновляет в таблице нужное поле для всех записей, у которых протух срок годности.

Comment: См. напр. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/825685/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8F/825729#825729

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. В таблице MySQL создать какое-нибудь поле, например, `end_date`, которое хранит дату окончания услуги (спасибо, Кэп).
2. Создаёшь функцию, которая выбирает все записи, у которых `end_date` совпадает с текущей датой и меняет значение в поле `package`.
3. Создаёшь команду, которая вызывает эту функцию.
4. Создаёшь крон, который раз в день (ну или чаще, смотри сам) вызывает команду из предыдущего пункта.
5. Вы великолепны.